# Adding a file with no read permission to perforce

Tags: perforce

I am doing black box testing on a tool that reads a file. One of the negative tests heck for the tool's behavior if the file is not readable. I have to submit that test on perforce with that file because they are checked out atomically everyday to run the tests. However, adding the file with no read permission to perforce failed. Is there any way to add a file with no read permission to perforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't add a file to Perforce if Perforce itself can't read the file.

For this type of testing, I'd suggest that the test should create the file programmatically with the correct permissions (and clean it up afterward) rather than being dependent on test data that gets synced from the depot.